# The domain of fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

Take the following:

$$f(x) = x^{6/4}$$

The domain of this function is all real numbers. This function can be simplified to:

$$f(x) = x^{3/2}$$

The domain of this function is all real numbers greater than or equal to 0. Why is this true? Why does simplifying the function change its domain?

Comment: I do not agree that the natural domain of the function given by the first expression is the set of all reals.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you explain why?

Comment: What happens when you try to evaluate the function at $-1$?

Comment: Because we want our function to be continuous as a function of the exponent. For negative $x$, and irrational exponent near $6/4$, the function is not defined. Also, $6/4=3/2$. We do not want definedness to depend on the form we use. Also, for $(-5)^{6/4}$, what if we decided to take the fourth root first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that
$$
x^{(m/n)} = (x^m)^{1/n}
$$
is only valid if $x$ is positive.  So in other words, while of course it is true that
$x^{(6/4)} = x^{(3/2)}$,
you seem to be interpreting this to mean $(x^6)^{1/4} = (x^3)^{1/2}$, which doesn't follow.

Comment: Ok - is that a rule of exponents?

Comment: @JackHumphries Yes, it's the rule $(a^b)^c = a^{(bc)}$.  But if $b$ and $c$ are not integers, then $a$ needs to be positive for it to be valid.